# ngDialog returns undefined view

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm using ngDialog js plugin, to open a view in a modal existing in another view :
I'm in **"items"** page(view) when I click new group, a popup appears where I can find the **"items groups"** view to add edit or delete a group.

Plugin is working fine, when I click new group, the popup modal appears but it doesn't return the groups view, it returns undefined.

My laravel project files

app
bootstrap
resources
storage..

I'm calling the template inside : resources/views/GroupsInv

code :

```
$scope.openNewAddItemForm = function () {
ngDialog.open({template: 'GroupsInv/GroupsInvView', className: 'ngDialog-  theme-default', plain: true, scope:$scope});
```

Problem : popup opens and shows "undefined". I don't know if the problem is the path.

Route working fine :

```
Route::get('/GroupsInvView', function () {
return view ('GroupsInv/GroupsInvView');
```

Comment: close your `template` argument with an apostrophe: `template: 'GroupsInv/GroupsInvView'`

Comment: it was a mistake while writing it here